# listing options in the selected tag through a SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve a value from `<select>` tag into `PHP`... the options in this selected tag is a function from `PHP` which lists those options from a separate `php` files called `functions.php`

see the function below from `functions.php`

```
function list_brand (){
  $sql = "SELECT brand FROM laptop
         ";
  $query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

  if ($query) {
     //echo 'success'; <-- testing the function functinality

     while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
           $brand = $query_row['brand'];

           echo '<option value="brand">'.$brand.'</option>';
     }      
  } else {echo 'fiald if';}
}
```

and below is the selected tag:

```
<select id="test" onchange="document.getElementById('text_content').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
    <option value="select">SELECT BRAND</option>
    <?php list_brand(); ?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="brand_text" id="text_content" value="" />
```

now my question is that i have two other selected tags that should list the options depending on that selected option in the first selected tag and that it should list thorough a SQL query

below is my full html code:

```
<form action="comparison.php" method="GET">
<table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Lap 1</td>
    <td colspan="2">Lap 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="19%">Brand</td>
    <td width="31%"><select><option value="brand1">==SELECT BRAND==</option>
                    <?php
                      list_brand();
                    ?>
                    </select></td>
    <td width="19%">Brand</td>
    <td width="31%"><select name="brand2"><option value="brand2">==SELECT BRAND==</option>
                    <?php
                      list_brand();
                    ?>
                    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="19">Model</td>
    <td width="31"><select><option value="model1">==SELECT MODEL==</option></select></td>

    <td width="19">Model</td>
    <td width="31"><select><option value="model2">==SELECT MODEL==</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="19">Partnumber</td>
    <td width="31"><select><option value="pn1">==SELECT PARTNUMBER==</option></select></td>

    <td width="19">Partnumber</td>
    <td width="31"><select><option value="pn2">==SELECT PARTNUMBER==</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="453" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Its not clear to me what a "tag" is in this context

Comment: First, you don't need to manage a "onCHange" to set the value in an input field, select are, like other input element, able to be submit on the form (if it has a name, you will get it on your $_GET, on the server side). Secondly, it appear that you want to update your second select depend on the value of the first select. Then, you should add a onChange listener on the first select, and when the value is changes, run an ajax request to refresh the second select.

Comment: hi. i did slipt ur comment dude. i just had to run two function on the "onchange" value and it did work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is it. I had to put two functions on OnChange one for assigning the selected value and the other is to submit the page so it can refresh...

```
 <form name="index" action="" method="GET">
  <select id="brand" onchange="document.getElementById('brand_content').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; document.index.submit();">
          <option value="">==SELECT BRAND==</option>
                      <?php
                        list_brand();
                      ?>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="brand_text" id="brand_content" value="" />

<?php
      $brand = $_GET['brand_text'];
      if (isset($brand)){

      }  else {echo 'no brand selected';}
?>
  <br>
  <select id="model" onchange="document.getElementById('model_content').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; document.index.submit(); ">>
  <option value="model1">==SELECT MODEL==</option>
  <?php
       list_model($brand);
  ?>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="model_text" id="model_content" value="" 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to handle this with a JavaScript solution, so you essentially want to use JavaScript to firstly check what option was selected in the first select tag, and then you would want to use JavaScript to then generate the contents for the second and third. The only way I can think of doing this is using an ajax request, as PHP is client side and parses once so it can't be changed once it has parsed.

Also, the `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated, you should consider using `PDO` or `MySQLi` in your future and current projects. You can read further on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Hi again... GOT IT SOLVED :) will post my solution tomorrow after God's well.